# Can i use loadrunner to test activeX web applications

Tags: loadrunner, activexobject

When i use loadrunner to test the web application ,i found the ie can't use activeX .Is it possible to use loadrunner to test activeX?

Comment: activeX still exists *on the web*?!

Comment: try Ajax Click & Script protocol, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use LoadRunner to test activeX.  Let's draw back to the architecture of ActiveX and then look at the paths to support the architecture.

ActiveX is a client side technology, essentially Microsoft's response to Java Applets. These items can be purely client-side, interface client-delight type items or actually communicate with a server.  There is some potential for data exchange and transformation as well.

If this is "client-delight" then there really isn't anything that needs to occur if you are recording at the transport layer.  All of the requests to the server will be collected and you will be able to address your modification of the script as you expect.

If this is some sort of load and transformation, then you have additional challenges if you wish to continue at the transport layer.  You may need to work with your development team to understand the algorithm's used to transform data.  You could implement this in your own code to affect transformation of what is to be returned.

If this is an applet which communicates to a server directly, then perhaps it leverages a standard protocol interface which is supported by LoadRunner.  In such a case a dual protocol recording, or recording via proxy may pick up the elements.

Lastly, if the whole app is activeX, it communicates directly with the host on an unknown protocol and you don't have access to developers to provide insight into the communications, then what can you do architecturally?  Well, in this case you move to the top of the OSI model and look at what options you have available to you to exercise the end user interface just as a user would do so.

Buzzy has already noted one route.  You might also try TruClient.  I think both of these items have issues as the ActiveX components typically live outside of the DOM environment managed by the browser.  This then leaves three options, a full blown GUI virtual user, a Citrix Virtual User, or a Remote Desktop Virtual User.  Each of these three options will allow you to drive the end user interface, essentially running a full browser and a full copy of the ActiveX components for each virtual user you wish to test with.

There is always a path.  Let your architectural expertise guide you on communications protocols and client-bound operations to find it.   This is why a command of these items are key as foundation class skills for performance testers/engineers/architects